# Pointer value from instance method being garbled. The cause seems to be dependent on buffer size

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers, printf, buffer

I am trying to create a an 1D-array of labels as a reference for content in the columns in another 2D-array. The labels contains both letters and numbers. Moreover, I would like the method to generic such that it works as wide variety of labels as possible.

Down below follows code and output.

```
main.m

#define IKOL           10
char *kolname [IKOL];    

for (int i = 0; i < IKOL; i++) {
    *(kolname + i) = " ";
}

sub *skuld =[[sub alloc]init];
[skuld set_name: kolname];
for (int i = 0; i < IKOL; i++) {
    printf("Main: kolname[%d] = %s\n", i, *(kolname + i));
}
```

The instance method:

```
sub.m
#define BUF           32

- (void)set_name: (char *[IKOL]) name {
    int number = 30;
    char label1[BUF];
    char label2[BUF];
    char label3[BUF];
    char label4[BUF];
    char test[12] = "Test2";
    *(name + 0) = "Port1";
    *(name + 1) = "Seq4";
    *(name + 2) = "GH-12";
    *(name + 3) = "Port5";
    snprintf(label1, sizeof(label1), "DDB(%d)", number);
    printf("Sub:  label1 = %s\n", label1);
    *(name + 4) = label1;
    snprintf(label2, sizeof(label2), "σ(%d)", (number-16));
    printf("Sub:  label2 = %s\n", label2);
    *(name + 5) = label2;
    snprintf(label3, sizeof(label3), "EMM(%d)", (number-7));
    printf("Sub:  label3 = %s\n", label3);
    *(name + 6) = label3;
    *(name + 7) = "Test1";
    *(name + 8) = test;
    printf("Sub:  test = %s\n", test);
}
```

If we alter BUF to 8 we will have the following output

```
Sub:  label1 = DDB(30)
Sub:  label2 = σ(14)
Sub:  label3 = EMM(23)
Sub:  test = Test2
Main: kolname[0] = Port1
Main: kolname[1] = Seq4
Main: kolname[2] = GH-12
Main: kolname[3] = Port5
Main: kolname[4] = \360\276\277_\377
Main: kolname[5] = \360\277\277_\377
Main: kolname[6] = 
Main: kolname[7] = Test1
Main: kolname[8] = Test2
Main: kolname[9] =  
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

The output will be strange for all BUF up to 24. If we set BUF to 25 we have desired output:

```
Sub:  label1 = DDB(30)
Sub:  label2 = σ(14)
Sub:  label3 = EMM(23)
Sub:  test = Test2
Main: kolname[0] = Port1
Main: kolname[1] = Seq4
Main: kolname[2] = GH-12
Main: kolname[3] = Port5
Main: kolname[4] = DDB(30)
Main: kolname[5] = σ(14)
Main: kolname[6] = EMM(23)
Main: kolname[7] = Test1
Main: kolname[8] = Test2
Main: kolname[9] =  
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Everything will look the same up to BUF = 33 where the main difference is that number 2 is missing in slot 8.

```
Sub:  label1 = DDB(30)
Sub:  label2 = σ(14)
Sub:  label3 = EMM(23)
Sub:  test = Test2
Main: kolname[0] = Port1
Main: kolname[1] = Seq4
Main: kolname[2] = GH-12
Main: kolname[3] = Port5
Main: kolname[4] = DDB(30)
Main: kolname[5] = σ(14)
Main: kolname[6] = EMM(23)
Main: kolname[7] = Test1
Main: kolname[8] = Test
Main: kolname[9] =  
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

If we increase BUF more, we will see even more strange output.
Here is an example for BUF = 50.

```
Sub:  label1 = DDB(30)
Sub:  label2 = σ(14)
Sub:  label3 = EMM(23)
Sub:  test = Test2
Main: kolname[0] = Port1
Main: kolname[1] = Seq4
Main: kolname[2] = GH-12
Main: kolname[3] = Port5
Main: kolname[4] = DDB(30)
Main: kolname[5] = σ(14)
Main: kolname[6] = 
Main: kolname[7] = Test1
Main: kolname[8] = \377
Main: kolname[9] =  
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Why doesn't the output become as I want for BUF under 25?
2. Why does it suddenly begin to work at BUF = 25. Does it have something to do with that the total number of characters (label1+…+label4) equals to 24?
3. Why does the output become strange again for BUF = 33 and over?

…and finally

4. How do I change the code to something that works for a wider variety of labels in terms of length (size)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buffers `label1`, `label2`, `label3`, `label4` and `test` are *stack allocated* inside `set_name`. Once `set_name` returns the lifetime of these buffers ends and the (stack) memory is available for re-use. Any results you observe once `set_name` returns are therefore essentially random.

If you wish to follow the same design, based on C strings, you will need to use dynamic/heap allocation of the buffers in `set_name`. This also means you will be responsible for later deallocation of those buffers.

If you are using Objective-C you might wish to consider using `NSString`, which will be automatically memory-managed under ARC.

Comment: I still don't understand why my method seems to be working for a small window, 24 < BUF < 33?

Comment: The appearance of working is a random result. When the stack allocated buffers are freed that does not mean the memory they used is cleared. When you later use, your now invalid, pointers they still refer to the same physical memory and it that memory has not been reused and completely overwritten fragments of what you stored there can be found.

Comment: Ahh, ok I understand. Thanks!